# NPM dependency conflicting

Tags: node.js, npm

After installing a newer version of node.js ( moving from node 14 to node 18), every time I want to install something in an older project, this list of errors pops up. I don't quite understand what it is related to and how to resolve the conflicts below.

```
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @vue/compiler-sfc@3.1.5
npm WARN Found: vue@3.2.19
npm WARN node_modules/vue
npm WARN   vue@"^3.1.5" from the root project
npm WARN   12 more (@vue/babel-preset-app, @vue/server-renderer, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer vue@"3.1.5" from @vue/compiler-sfc@3.1.5
npm WARN node_modules/@vue/compiler-sfc
npm WARN   dev @vue/compiler-sfc@"^3.0.0" from the root project
npm WARN   1 more (@vue/cli-service)
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: vue@3.1.5
npm WARN node_modules/vue
npm WARN   peer vue@"3.1.5" from @vue/compiler-sfc@3.1.5
npm WARN   node_modules/@vue/compiler-sfc
npm WARN     dev @vue/compiler-sfc@"^3.0.0" from the root project
npm WARN     1 more (@vue/cli-service)
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @vue/composition-api@0.3.4
npm WARN Found: vue@3.2.19
npm WARN node_modules/vue
npm WARN   vue@"^3.1.5" from the root project
npm WARN   12 more (@vue/babel-preset-app, @vue/server-renderer, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer vue@"^2.5.22" from @vue/composition-api@0.3.4
npm WARN node_modules/@vue/composition-api
npm WARN   peer @vue/composition-api@"^0.3.2" from vue-use-web@1.0.1
npm WARN   node_modules/vue-use-web
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: vue@2.7.14
npm WARN node_modules/vue
npm WARN   peer vue@"^2.5.22" from @vue/composition-api@0.3.4
npm WARN   node_modules/@vue/composition-api
npm WARN     peer @vue/composition-api@"^0.3.2" from vue-use-web@1.0.1
npm WARN     node_modules/vue-use-web
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @vueup/vue-quill@1.0.0-beta.8
npm WARN Found: vue@3.2.19
npm WARN node_modules/vue
npm WARN   vue@"^3.1.5" from the root project
npm WARN   12 more (@vue/babel-preset-app, @vue/server-renderer, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer vue@"^3.2.31" from @vueup/vue-quill@1.0.0-beta.8
npm WARN node_modules/@vueup/vue-quill
npm WARN   @vueup/vue-quill@"^1.0.0-beta.8" from the root project
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: vue@3.2.47
npm WARN node_modules/vue
npm WARN   peer vue@"^3.2.31" from @vueup/vue-quill@1.0.0-beta.8
npm WARN   node_modules/@vueup/vue-quill
npm WARN     @vueup/vue-quill@"^1.0.0-beta.8" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: primevue@3.12.5
npm WARN Found: primeicons@4.1.0
npm WARN node_modules/primeicons
npm WARN   primeicons@"^4.1.0" from the root project
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer primeicons@"^5.0.0" from primevue@3.12.5
npm WARN node_modules/primevue
npm WARN   primevue@"^3.12.5" from the root project
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: primeicons@5.0.0
npm WARN node_modules/primeicons
npm WARN   peer primeicons@"^5.0.0" from primevue@3.12.5
npm WARN   node_modules/primevue
npm WARN     primevue@"^3.12.5" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: sass-loader@12.1.0
npm WARN Found: webpack@4.46.0
npm WARN node_modules/webpack
npm WARN   peer webpack@"^4.0.0" from @intervolga/optimize-cssnano-plugin@1.0.6
npm WARN   node_modules/@intervolga/optimize-cssnano-plugin
npm WARN     @intervolga/optimize-cssnano-plugin@"^1.0.5" from @vue/cli-service@4.5.13
npm WARN     node_modules/@vue/cli-service
npm WARN   19 more (@soda/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer webpack@"^5.0.0" from sass-loader@12.1.0
npm WARN node_modules/sass-loader
npm WARN   sass-loader@"^12.1.0" from the root project
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: webpack@5.75.0
npm WARN node_modules/webpack
npm WARN   peer webpack@"^5.0.0" from sass-loader@12.1.0
npm WARN   node_modules/sass-loader
npm WARN     sass-loader@"^12.1.0" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: vue-clickaway@2.2.2
npm WARN Found: vue@3.2.19
npm WARN node_modules/vue
npm WARN   vue@"^3.1.5" from the root project
npm WARN   12 more (@vue/babel-preset-app, @vue/server-renderer, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer vue@"^2.0.0" from vue-clickaway@2.2.2
npm WARN node_modules/vue-clickaway
npm WARN   vue-clickaway@"^2.2.2" from vue-context@6.0.0
npm WARN   node_modules/vue-context
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: vue@2.7.14
npm WARN node_modules/vue
npm WARN   peer vue@"^2.0.0" from vue-clickaway@2.2.2
npm WARN   node_modules/vue-clickaway
npm WARN     vue-clickaway@"^2.2.2" from vue-context@6.0.0
npm WARN     node_modules/vue-context
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: vue-demi@0.11.4
npm WARN Found: @vue/composition-api@0.3.4
npm WARN node_modules/@vue/composition-api
npm WARN   peer @vue/composition-api@"^0.3.2" from vue-use-web@1.0.1
npm WARN   node_modules/vue-use-web
npm WARN     vue-use-web@"^1.0.1" from the root project
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peerOptional @vue/composition-api@"^1.0.0-rc.1" from vue-demi@0.11.4
npm WARN node_modules/vue-demi
npm WARN   vue-demi@"*" from @vueuse/core@5.3.0
npm WARN   node_modules/@vueuse/core
npm WARN   2 more (@vueuse/integrations, @vueuse/shared)
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: @vue/composition-api@1.7.1
npm WARN node_modules/@vue/composition-api
npm WARN   peerOptional @vue/composition-api@"^1.0.0-rc.1" from vue-demi@0.11.4
npm WARN   node_modules/vue-demi
npm WARN     vue-demi@"*" from @vueuse/core@5.3.0
npm WARN     node_modules/@vueuse/core
npm WARN     2 more (@vueuse/integrations, @vueuse/shared)
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: vue-js-modal@2.0.1
npm WARN Found: vue@3.2.19
npm WARN node_modules/vue
npm WARN   vue@"^3.1.5" from the root project
npm WARN   12 more (@vue/babel-preset-app, @vue/server-renderer, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer vue@"^2.6.11" from vue-js-modal@2.0.1
npm WARN node_modules/vue-js-modal
npm WARN   vue-js-modal@"^2.0.1" from the root project
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: vue@2.7.14
npm WARN node_modules/vue
npm WARN   peer vue@"^2.6.11" from vue-js-modal@2.0.1
npm WARN   node_modules/vue-js-modal
npm WARN     vue-js-modal@"^2.0.1" from the root project
```

As far as I can see, a version-related error pops up for most of the modules I have installed. On the node 14 version everything works.

Answer (score 0):

These warnings indicate conflicts between different versions of packages that are installed in your project. These conflicts occur when a package has a peer dependency on a specific version of another package, but there is already a different version of that package installed in your project.

To resolve these conflicts, you can try updating or downgrading the version of the conflicting package or installing the missing peer dependency directly in your project. You can also try deleting the node_modules folder and running npm install to install all packages again from scratch.

Comment: the problem occurs when any npm install command is executed

Answer (score 0):

> node 14.*.* uses npm 6.*.* version
>
> node 18.*.* uses npm 8.*.* version

https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/

Resolving dependenies works differently. You can find out more on npm config page: [https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/config?v=true#legacy-peer-deps)

or use flag `legacy-peer-deps` but it's not recommended, as it will not enforce the peerDependencies contract that meta-dependencies may rely on